# I am receiving the following error message: ORA-06550: line 2, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I don't know what I did wrong. I followed my professors instructions.
I am receiving the following error message :

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date    pipe

This is my code:

```
IF :REQUEST = 'UPDATE' THEN 

   #OWNER#.ACAD_DEPART_TAPI.UPD_ACAD_DEPT( 
   P_DEPT_ID => :P30_DEPT_ID, 
   P_DEPT_SHORT_NAME => :P30_DEPT_SHORT_NAME, 
   P_DEPT_NAME => :P30_DEPT_NAME, 
   P_MD5 => :P30_MD5); 
   :P30_DEPT_ID := NULL ; 

ELSIF  :REQUEST = 'INSERT' THEN 

   #OWNER#.ACAD_DEPART_TAPI.INS_ACAD_DEPT( 
   P_DEPT_ID => :P30_DEPT_ID, 
   P_DEPT_SHORT_NAME => :P30_DEPT_SHORT_NAME, 
   P_DEPT_NAME => :P30_DEPT_NAME ) ; 
   :P30_DEPT_ID := NULL ; 

ELSIF  :REQUEST = 'CLEAR' THEN 
   :P30_DEPT_ID := NULL ; 

ELSIF :REQUEST = 'DELETE' THEN 

   #OWNER#.ACAD_DEPART_TAPI.DEL_ACAD_DEPT(P_DEPT_ID =>  
   :P30_DEPT_ID) ; :P30_DEPT_ID := NULL ; 

END IF ;
```

Comment: This `#OWNER#` seems to be the issue.

Comment: Odd that it's complaining about line 2, unless you added the blank line for posting; maybe you have a control character at the end of that line?

Comment: I  changed the spacing, and I always get an error on line 2. I'm new with apex (noob), so I am completely stuck.

Comment: where is this being pasted? is it complaining because the particular attribute is expecting a query instead?